# How to apply style on StaticTextItem component of DynamicForm in SmartGWT?

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt, smartclient

I want to apply style on StaticTextItem in SmartGWT's DynamicForm item.

I did not find any method like setStyleName for this component.

Is there any alternate way to apply style on StaticTextItem?

I have also noticed that ToolStrip Component can add only Form items, So Here I am stuck how would I apply a style particularly on StaticTextItem.

My goal is just add label with style on ToolStrip.

Any alternative to this appreciated!!!

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following properties to apply styles to StaticTextItem:

```
staticTextItem.setTextBoxStyle(textBoxStyle);
staticTextItem.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
```

Comment: It seems bit confusing. Why they haven't kept it like setStyleName as it there for other components?