# smartgwt StaticTextItem set css style

Tags: css, gwt, smartgwt

I'm trying to set an specific CSS just for a certain item on my form.  I would like to make it bold and in a different color.  I used the following statement. Why is it not working?

```
    myStaticTextItem.setCellStyle("color:#FF0000; font-weight: bold;");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9207036/how-to-apply-style-on-statictextitem-component-of-dynamicform-in-smartgwt

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setTextBoxStyle` to assign CSS class to your input box of that element.

There are additional methods for assigning CSS classes for special parts of element like title, hover, hint and picker icon. More [here](https://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/StaticTextItem.html).

Comment: I also tried with the setTextBoxStyle, but it's not working either

Comment: Hmm, it's a lot of code... but this is supposed to be very simple, it's just an StaticTextItem that is part of a form...

Comment: Im not sure. Might be that some other CSS rule of parent element is overriding your new style.